# Exercise 9, Section 2.3 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, proof-writing, independence

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a subfield $F$ of the complex numbers. Suppose $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are linearly independent vectors in $V$. Prove that $(\alpha +\beta)$, $(\beta +\gamma)$ and $(\gamma +\alpha)$ are linearly independent.

**My attempt:** Since $\alpha \neq \gamma$, $\beta \neq \alpha$, $\beta \neq \gamma$, we have $(\alpha +\beta) \neq (\beta +\gamma)$, $(\beta +\gamma) \neq (\gamma +\alpha)$, $(\alpha +\beta)\neq (\gamma +\alpha)$. This is necessary condition for linear independence and “unnecessary detail” in proof. If $x_1 \cdot (\alpha +\beta)+x_2 \cdot (\beta +\gamma) +x_3 \cdot (\gamma +\alpha)=0_V$. So $(x_1 \cdot \alpha +x_1 \cdot \beta) +(x_2\cdot \beta +x_2 \cdot \gamma )+(x_3 \cdot \gamma +x_3 \cdot \alpha) =0_V$. By distributive axiom of vector space, $(x_1+x_3) \cdot \alpha+(x_1+x_2) \cdot \beta+(x_2+x_3)\cdot \gamma=0_V$. Since $\{\alpha, \beta, \gamma\}$ is independent, $(x_1+x_3)=(x_1+x_2)=(x_2+x_3)=0_F$. Which implies $x_1=x_2=x_3=0_F$. Hence $\{(\alpha +\beta) ,(\beta +\gamma) ,(\gamma +\alpha)\}$ is linearly independent. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: I would elaborate more on why that implies that $x_1=x_2=x_3=0_F$, but otherwise looks good.

Comment: This is objectively fine, but my mind cannot accept that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are the vectors, while $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are the scalars!

Comment: @Yagger I thought solving equation is messy, that’s why I didn’t show it.

Comment: @TheoBendit I can understand your feeling. You’re custom to use certain notation for vectors and scalars. Unfortunately Hoffman’s use $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ for vectors and $x_1,x_2,x_3$ for scalars.

Comment: If you want to avoid solving a system of equations call $v_1=\alpha +\beta,$ $v_2=\beta +\gamma,$ $v_3=\gamma+\alpha.$ Observe that $\alpha={1\over 2}[v_1-v_2+v_3],$ $\beta={1\over 2}[v_1+v_2-v_3],$ $\gamma={1\over 2}[-v_1+v_2+v_3].$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct. You used the linearity of $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$, to show that the pairwise summation of elements is also linearly independent.